# optimizing JQuery SmoothScroll script

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

The script below acieves the task, but I need it to run another 20 time or so. How can I optimize the script so I don`t need to call the same script over and over again?

"a1" changes to "a2", "a3" and so on. "#thing" needs to change also so it can scroll to another part of the page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".a1").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#thing").offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that can do the job i think:

```
var cnt = 0;
$(".a1").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#schoonmaak").offset().top
    }, 500, function() {
      if (cnt++ > 20) $(".a1").click();   
});
```

EDIT - after your question edit has made, i think this will solve your problem:

```
var items = $('body ul li[id]');
$('.nobackground h2 a').each(function(i){

  $(this).click(function() {
     $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(items[i]).offset().top}, 500);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I`ve not been clear what I want. "a1" changes to "a2", "a3" and so on. "#schoonmaak" changes also to something else.